# User Agents for IE7 and IE8 on Windows XP - Java

Tags: java, internet-explorer, if-statement, syntax, user-agent

I'm very new to user agents, and I'm fairly stuck on how to make this work.

What we have in the code, is a series of if statements that check the user agent, and display a PDF properly.  BUT we're running into an issue where the PDF will not display properly in an object tag with IE7 and IE8 on WindowsXP, so I need to modify the if statements to add an elseif to allow for people who view the PDF on IE7 and IE8 on WindowsXP for it to render out in an iframe. My problem is proper syntax.

Here's the code:

```
String pdfpath = (String) request.getAttribute("pdfpath");
    String ua = request.getHeader("User-Agent").toLowerCase();

    if (ua.matches("(?i).*((android|bb\\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino|android|ipad|playbook|silk).*")||ua.substring(0,4).matches("(?i)1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\\-(n|u)|c55\\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\\-5|g\\-mo|go(\\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\\-(m|p|t)|hei\\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\\-c|ht(c(\\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\\-|\\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\\-w|m3ga|m50\\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\\-g|qa\\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\\-[2-7]|i\\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\\-|oo|p\\-)|sdk\\/|se(c(\\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\\-|shar|sie(\\-|m)|sk\\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\\-|v\\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\\-|tdg\\-|tel(i|m)|tim\\-|t\\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\\-|m3|m5)|tx\\-9|up(\\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\\-|your|zeto|zte\\-")) {

      response.sendRedirect(pdfpath);

    } else if (ua.matches("msie 7.0"|"msie8.0")){
        <iframe src="<%=pdfpath %>" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
    } else {
        <object data="<%=pdfpath %>" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
    }
```

I ONLY need to focus on the syntax of the elseif (ua.matches)

Do I have this right? Where can I find a list of proper syntax for IE7 and IE8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It'll look for the values "MSIE 7.0" or "MSIE 8.0" in the user agent.

```
} else if (ua.matches(".*MSIE [78][.]0.*")) {
```

Here's how that regular expression breaks down:

1. `.*` Matches zero or more characters.
2. `MSIE` Matches the literal string "MSIE ".
3. `[78]` Matches either a "7" or "8".
4. `[.]` Matches a period. "." should also accomplish the same thing.
5. `0` Matches a literal "0".
6. `.*` Matches zero or more characters.

Overall it effectively means the regular expression will match "MSIE 7.0" or "MSIE 8.0" surrounded by any number of other characters.

I based those values on:

- [Common User Agent Strings](http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/CommonUserAgents)
- [The Internet Explorer 8 User-Agent String](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/02/21/the-internet-explorer-8-user-agent-string.aspx)
- [Ridonkulously large index of user agent strings](http://useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php)

Comment: I'll give it a whirl... I would like to learn more about this. Can you  tell me either what ".*MSIE [78][.]0.*" means, or point me to a site that can show me all the ins and out of user-agents?

Comment: I'll update the answer to explain the regular expression and link to a massive index of user agent strings.

Comment: ok.. well that didn't work.  I fired up the page on my WinXP machine with both IE7 and IE8 and both browsers brought up the third ELSE option (object embed)

Comment: I found the issue... you have in the example MSIE, but in the code I gave, I have .toLowerCase().  I assume its case sensitive, because as soon as I changed it to msie, it worked just fine!

Comment: Arg, I totally missed that in your code! Good catch, glad it worked out for you.

Comment: apparently, I need to add a catch for IE9, IE10, IE11 and Safari. Now it makes sense for [789], but what do you do for IE in the double digits?

Comment: You can create a capture group to cover those scenarios: ".*msie ([789]|1[01])[.]0.*". This should cover IE7 through IE11.

Comment: I cannot seem to get the user-agent for safari.

Comment: Look for "applewebkit" in your string.

Comment: +Erik Gillespie I hate to be a bother once more, but I want to make sure I have the logic and syntax correct with some modifications:  Say I wanted IE 9, 10 and 11 on the IF, I would put (.*msie (9|1[01])[.]0.*) and on the else I wanted IE 7 and *, I would put (.*msie [78][.]0.*).